# Nuxt.js (webpack), multiple static folders?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

Is there any way to extend static (public) nuxt folder and add another one?

Like:

```
/components
/pages
...
/static
/somethingsomething2
   /static2
/somethingsomething3
   /static3
```

I am trying to achieve modularized architecture (DDD like)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wonders about this, I've found this nuxt module

`https://github.com/nuxt-community/modules/tree/master/packages/vendor`

And it gave me and idea to use symlinks :)

`fs.ensureSymlinkSync(sourceFolderPath, destinationFolderPath, 'junction')`